# Drag & drop with 2 lists - both list activate same OnDrop event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui-sortable

Am using jQuery Sortable plugin for drag abd drop, being taken out of here:
http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/
I have 2 "UL" - list:

```
ul class="dragList" id="VecInventorList"
 ul class="unStyledList" id="UnchoosedVehInvList"
```

And following on my javascript:

```
$("ul.unStyledList").sortable({
        group: 'no-drop',
        drag: false,
        onDrop: function (item, targetContainer, _super) {
        }
      });
  $("ul.dragList").sortable({
        group: 'no-drop',
        drag: false,
        onDrop: function (item, targetContainer, _super) {
        }
      });
```

Drag is possible inside "dragList" (replace position between items) and from "dragList"
to "unStyledList" (take them out of the "dragList" list).
On both cases (drag inside "dragList" and out of "dragList"), the 1st OnDrop function is working.
Please advise how can I use 2 OnDrop function, each for any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onDrop is called on the container the item came from.  In your function, evaluate to targetContainer parameter to see where the item was dropped and decide how to handle it.

Comment: That's what I'd thought to do, but can't I make 2 seperate onDrop function, when dropping to list A will trigger function A and dropping to list B will trigger function B?

Comment: sure, make 2 separate functions and in your onDrop function look at targetContainer to decide which of those functions to call

Comment: I meant 2 onDrop funcs as I written above, which both would be active each on every event... probably immposible so will do as you said, thank you :)